# Where does new blood comes from when penis get erected?

Tags: sex, sexual-reproduction, sexuality

In Humans, During sexual arousal in males, his penis will get erected with blood.

Where does this new blood coming to fill his penis which is required for erection ?

Comment: There are areas in our body which act as reservoir for blood , so when a body part needs excess of it can be diverted to it. ex: lungs.

Comment: see this : http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20174/where-does-extra-blood-come-from-to-fill-your-muscles-during-exercise?noredirect=1&lq=1